# Xml editing on changable schema

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml

I need some opinions. I'm trying to write an XML editor but XML schema and values can be changeable on UI. For example, let's assume my current schema is like

> c: child , e: element, at: attribute, k: element of element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<root>
    <c1 at1="value" at2="value" at3="value">
        <e1>
            <k1 at3="value" at4="value"></k1>
        </e1>
    </c1>
    <c2>
        <e2 at5="value" at6="value" at7="value" at8="value">
            <k1>
                <e2 at9="value"></e2>
            </k1>
        </e2>
    </c2>
</root>
```

as you see schema doesn't have any generics and **it won't**. everything in the xml file can be changed. I know how to parse, how to manipulate XML file on either Server-side or Client-side but when it comes to dynamic XML parse and editing, my brain hurts. At the end of it, I'm planning to design an UI for manipulating data and export my new XML from there. And next time i can edit my last XML file and take new version of my file, it goes like this. I need some advices with my back-end coding. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem, it's a system design problem. No-one should attempt to help you with a system design based on a 200-word requirements statement; there are far too many unknown factors to make this a realistic exercise.

Comment: How come? I'm just asking some advices to hit the road. Are you starting a project without any thought? It's literally **impossible**. There is no/one solution for my problem. You can just give an advice like _Hey, maybe it's related with your problem, please check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/)!_ I just wanted your friendly advices.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is designed for solving coding problems, and the mods are pretty strict about keeping things on-topic.